# Html5 drag and drop on svg element

Tags: jquery, html, svg, drag-and-drop

I am trying to follow the html5 drag and drop tutorial [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/tutorials/dnd/basics/). I could not get the `dragstart` event to be registered on `rect` element. If I change the event from `draggable` to `mousedown` it calls the `handleDragStart` handler. Please ignore the additional blank registration in the code.

JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/YNReB/)

---

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <style type="text/css" media="screen">
    svg rect { cursor: move; }
  </style>
</head><body>
  <h1>SVG/HTML 5 Example</h1>
  <svg id="cvs">
    <rect draggable="true" x="0" y="10" width="100" height="80" fill="#69c" />
    <rect x="50" y="50" width="90" height="50" fill="#c66" />        
  </svg>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="loc.js"></script>
</body></html>
```

**loc.js**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {    
    function handleDragStart(e) {
        log("handleDragStart");                
          this.style.opacity = '0.4';  // this ==> e.target is the source node.
    };

    var registercb = function () {
            $("#cvs > rect").each(function() {
                  $(this).attr('draggable', 'true');
              });
            $("#cvs > rect").bind('dragstart', handleDragStart);    
            $(window).mousedown(function (e) {        

            });    
            $(window).mousemove(function (e) {                
            });
            $(window).mouseup(function (e) {
                log("mouseup");                
            });
        };

    function log() {
      if (window.console && window.console.log)
        window.console.log('[XXX] ' + Array.prototype.join.call(arguments, ' '));
    };

    registercb();
});
```

Answer (score 19):

I know this is an old question, I arrived here from [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30798377/how-to-drag-drop-svg-elements) that was marked as a duplicate of this one, and wanted to add a possible solution that doesn't require jQuery or any libraries, and that works in all major browsers. It is based on [this tutorial](http://www.petercollingridge.co.uk/interactive-svg-components/draggable-svg-element) recommended by [@AmirHossein Mehrvarzi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1743997/amirhossein-mehrvarzi).

This small solution doesn't use the drag events, just the `mousedown`, `mouseup` and `mousemove`. This is how it works:

- When the mouse is down on the rectangle, it saves the mouse position and the active element.
- When the mouse moves, the rectangle coordinates are updated with the new mouse position.
- When the mouse is up, it resets the active element.

From the code in the question above:

```js
var selectedElement = null;
var currentX = 0;
var currentY = 0;

$(document).ready(function() {
    
    function handleDragStart(e) {
        log("handleDragStart");                
        this.style.opacity = '0.4';  // this ==> e.target is the source node.
    };
    
    var registercb = function () {
       
        $("#cvs > rect").mousedown(function (e) {
            // save the original values when the user clicks on the element
            currentX = e.clientX;
            currentY = e.clientY;
            selectedElement = e.target;
        }).mousemove(function (e) {    
            // if there is an active element, move it around by updating its coordinates           
            if (selectedElement) {
                var dx = parseInt(selectedElement.getAttribute("x")) + e.clientX - currentX;
                var dy = parseInt(selectedElement.getAttribute("y")) + e.clientY - currentY;
                currentX = e.clientX;
                currentY = e.clientY;
                selectedElement.setAttribute("x", dx);
                selectedElement.setAttribute("y", dy);
            }
        }).mouseup(function (e) {
            // deactivate element when the mouse is up
            selectedElement = null;  
        });
    };
    
    function log() {
        if (window.console && window.console.log)
            window.console.log('[XXX] ' + Array.prototype.join.call(arguments, ' '));
    };
    
    registercb();
});
```

```css
rect { cursor: move; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>SVG/HTML 5 Example</h1>
<svg id="cvs">
    <rect x="0" y="10" width="100" height="80" fill="#69c" />
    <rect x="50" y="50" width="90" height="50" fill="#c66" />        
</svg>
```

You can also see it on this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YNReB/61/

If you want to add drop functionality, you can modify the `mouseup` function to read the element on the cursor position (with `document.elementFromPoint(e.clientX, e.clientY)`) and then you can perform actions on the original element and the one where it was dropped.

Answer (score 11):

This behavior may be caused by several reasons:

- HTML 5 drag and drop is a mess, [according to this article](http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2009/09/the_html5_drag.html). I know it's a bit older, but the issue still seems not to be solved
- jQuery does not support the SVG DOM-model. Therefore some parts of it may work, others don't (like `offset()` or `width()`).

I'd definitely not rely on HTML5 drag & drop support right now, but rather use a library to handle this issue. If you want to work with SVG, you could try [Raphaël](http://raphaeljs.com/). If you need jQuery too, maybe the [SVG plugin](http://keith-wood.name/svg.html) is the way to go. Note that both projects are not actively developed at the moment.
I know this is not really a satisfactory answer, but I had to learn too, that jQuery and SVG do not go that well together. Hopefully someone proves me wrong ;).