# How to Drag & Drop SVG elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I want to exchange the elements of this puzzle by Drag & Drop instead of swap by click. Indeed i want to make a triangle puzzle, that my web users be able to fill the blank fields by some elements and exchange the elements of that puzzle, by drag and drop. like this [example image](http://cdn.tutsplus.com/active/uploads/legacy/tuts/403_html5TileSwapPuzzle/demo/puzzle.html).

What should I do?! plz help me.

[Fiddle here...](http://jsfiddle.net/4x7sh6bj/6/)

```js
var step = 0;
var $prev;

$("polygon").on("click", function() {
    switch (step) {
        // if it's the first step: save the current element for later
        case 0:
            step = 1;
            $prev = $(this);
            break;
        // if it's the second step: swap images and start again
        case 1:
            step = 0;
            var aux = $prev.attr("fill");
            $prev.attr("fill", $(this).attr("fill"));
            $(this).attr("fill", aux);
            break;
    }
});
```

```css
polygon, path {
    opacity:0.5;
    transition:all 0.5s;
}

polygon:hover, path:hover {
    opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<svg width="450" height="450">
    <defs>
        <pattern id="img1" width="100%" height="100%">
            <image xlink:href="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/people/" x="0" y="0" width="200" height="200" />
        </pattern>
        <pattern id="img2" width="100%" height="100%">
            <image xlink:href="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/animals/" x="0" y="0" width="200" height="200" />
        </pattern>
        <pattern id="img3" width="100%" height="100%">
            <image xlink:href="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/abstract/" x="0" y="0" width="200" height="200" />
        </pattern>
        <pattern id="img4" width="100%" height="100%">
            <image xlink:href="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/sports/" x="0" y="0" width="200" height="200"/>
        </pattern>
    </defs>
    <polygon id="path1" points="225,450 300,300 150,300" fill="url(#img1)" />
    <polygon id="path2" points="150,300 225,150 75,150" fill="url(#img2)" />
    <polygon id="path3" points="150,300 300,300 225,150" fill="url(#img3)" />
    <polygon id="path4" points="300,300 375,150 225,150" fill="url(#img4)" />
    <polygon id="path5" points="75,150 150,0 0,0" fill="url(#img1)" />
    <polygon id="path6" points="75,150 225,150 150,0" fill="url(#img2)" />
    <polygon id="path7" points="225,150 300,0 150,0" fill="url(#img3)" />
    <polygon id="path8" points="225,150 375,150 300,0" fill="url(#img4)" />
    <polygon id="path9" points="375,150 450,0 300,0" fill="url(#img1)" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Enter link description here...

Comment: @Paul LeBeau can you help me?!

Comment: @PraveenKumar i was put links. "http://cdn.tutsplus.com/active/uploads/legacy/tuts/403_html5TileSwapPuzzle/demo/puzzle.html"     "http://jsfiddle.net/4x7sh6bj/6/"

Comment: I know, edit your question correctly. That's what I meant!

Comment: @PraveenKumar  Indeed i want to make a triangle puzzle, that my web users be able to fill the blank fields by some elements and exchange the elements of that puzzle, by drag and drop.

Comment: I understood everything what you said. Well, you didn't understand what I am asking you to do. Read your question and find if there's anything wrong! `;)`

Comment: @PraveenKumar please visit this link: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-an-html5-canvas-tile-swapping-puzzle--active-10747

Comment: Ha ha. You never understand me. Lemme myself edit.

Comment: Did you understand what I was asking you to edit?

Comment: See http://www.petercollingridge.co.uk/interactive-svg-components/draggable-svg-element

Comment: I think this question should be reopened, the linked question doesn't really have a solution but a "check this library" reply, and doesn't specify how to do the drag & drop at all

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro thanks for advise,but what should i do exactly to earn suitable and wanted answer?!

Comment: @hgh I answered the question that is mentioned above with an example from the tutorial suggested by AmirHossein Mehrvarzi. I also made a version that fits your case, and that you can see here http://jsfiddle.net/92g6afn7/

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Thanks a looot! You solved my problem exactly! tnxx :) Can i use cropped images in triangle shapes (.PNG) for fit the elements on this puzzle?!