# HTML 5 SVG With Drag and Drop

Tags: html

I want to Drag a image into a SVG circle. While debugging image is available as a child but it's not showing on circle. When I dragging the same image into a `<div>` element it's working fine but not for `<SVG>` or `<Image>` tag. With `<div>` it's working fine but not with `<IMAGE>`.

Q . Draw a circles of color yellow and green using SVG and allow users to drag and drop a logo  into the circles .

https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FVF69MCUNTQ0

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Html5 drag and drop on svg element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5864249/html5-drag-and-drop-on-svg-element)

Answer (score 2):

You can not use drag events in SVGs but there is a trick. You can have two sections (one overlaying the other) by setting the z-index property on one of the sections.
Have a look at below code :

CSS :

```
        #container{
            text-align: center;
            margin: -20px 20% 0 20%;
            background: #b9cae5;
        }
        #SVGs{
            width:100px;
            height:100px;
            margin: 20px 0 0 350px;
            position:relative;

        }
        .sec1,.sec2{
            width:100px;
            height:100px;
            position:absolute;
            top:0;
            left:0;
        }
        .sec1{
            z-index:10;
        }
```

in your HTML :

```
<section id ="container">
    <section id="SVGs">

            <section class="sec2">
            <svg width="100" height="100">

                <circle id="abc" cx="50" cy="50" r="50" stroke="black" fill="yellow">
                </circle>
            </svg>
            </section>
            <section id="sec1"class="sec1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
            </section>

       <br/><br/>
       </section>
       <section>
               <p> <strong>Drag the gif image to the SVG circles above.</strong>
       </p>
       <img id="drg1" alt="Check Internet Connection"src="https://media.giphy.com/media/l3vR16pONsV8cKkWk/giphy.gif" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="100" height="100"/>

       </section>
```

and your script :

```
    <script>
            function allowDrop(ev) {
                ev.preventDefault();
            }

            function drag(ev) {
                ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
            }

            function drop(ev) {
                ev.preventDefault();
                var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
                ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));

            }
            </script>
```

I hope it helps :)